Adding ROS2 to a project already using Conan
First of all:  I'm not trying to treat ROS2 Humble as a Conan package.  I have a pre-existing codebase that is using conan for a few dependencies, I would like like to add ROS2 as a dependency.
# I needed to manually include directories (first sign that something's not right)
target_include_directories(myLib PUBLIC 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    /opt/ros/humble/include/rosidl_runtime_cpp
    /opt/ros/humble/include/rosidl_runtime_c
    )
target_link_libraries(myLib PUBLIC   
    Boost::json    # Boost 1.85 from Conan
    Boost::system
    Boost::url
    Threads::Threads
    SQLite::SQLite3  # System SQLite
    rosidl_runtime_cpp 
    rosidl_runtime_c 
    rclcpp      
    std_msgs    
)

The resulting compiler command indicates that the the library path is not set:
 /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-13/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/13/ld: cannot find -lstd_msgs: No such file or directory

I also tried using ament_target_dependencies, but that didn't seem to recognize the boost components (e.g. boost::json).
Any recommendations?

Are you using find_package(rclcpp) and so? That is the standard way yo include the ROS libraries into you CMake project.
Anyway, a bit more of context would be helpful: Are you developing inside a colcon workspace activating the ros environment before building? What is your development flow?
